# right join of Yii2 framework

Tags: yii2, right-join

## view

```
<?php 
$url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['admin/sale/prduct']);
?>
```

script code in view page 
send id whit GET

## script in view page

```
<script>

function ddlcategor(id){
$.ajax({
 type:'GET',
url:'<?=$url?>',
data:{id:id},
success: function(data){
$("#test").html(data);
}
});
}

</script>
```

controller document !

## controller

```
<?php

public function actionProduct($id){
    $products = Yii::db->createCommand('select products.* from products right join (select * from product_category where product_category.cat_pro_id ='.$id.') as t on(products.id = t.product_id)')->queryAll();

$option ='';
echo "<option>select ...</option>";
foreach($products  as $value){
  $option.="<option value=$value->id>$value->title</option>";
}

return $option;

}

?>
```

## Error

> PHP Notice - yii\base\ErrorException typing to get property of
>   non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Yii::$app->db->createCommand()` **returns array**. Each row is an associative array with column names and values.
if the selection returns nothing, an **empty array** will be received.

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->queryAll();
```

In your example **$value not objact**. It is array:

```
$products = Yii::db->createCommand('select products.* from products right join (select * from product_category where product_category.cat_pro_id ='.$id.') as t on(products.id = t.product_id)')->queryAll();

$option ='';
//No needed in this variant
//echo "<option>select ...</option>";
If(!empty($products)){
   foreach($products  as $value){
      $option.="<option value=$value['id']>$value['title']</option>";
   }
}else{
    $option.= "<option selected disabled>No results!</option>"
}
return $option;
```

To debug ajax result I recommend using https://www.getpostman.com/
Using this service, you can track results and errors returned by url pasted to ajax simply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function actionProduct($id){
      $commands = Yii::$app->getDb();
      $products = $commands->createCommand('select products.* from products right join (select * from product_category where product_category.cat_pro_id ='.$id.') as t on(products.id = t.product_id)')->queryAll();    
        $option ='';
        echo "<option>select ...</option>";
        foreach($products  as $value){
          $option.="<option value=$value['id']>$value['title']</option>";
        }    
    return $option;    
    }
```